# Повторить запрос insert много раз (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Суть такова:
Нужно выполнить запрос insert 20 раз, но не брутфорсом (многократное повторение не вариант). **Есть ли какая-нибудь функция для этого?**

Запрос делает что:
создает строку с тремя заглавными и тремя не заглавными буквами.

В итоге должно получится такое:

[image: Результирующая таблица]

Сам запрос выглядит так:

```
insert into familiabigt(txt) values (concat(array_to_string(ARRAY(
    SELECT chr((ascii('A') + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) 
    FROM generate_series(1,3)),''),
      lower(array_to_string(ARRAY(
    SELECT chr((ascii('A') + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) 
    FROM generate_series(1,3)),'')))
         );
```

Comment: Соедините свою строку с вспомогательной таблицей, содержащей 20 строк (cross join). Но, вероятно, тогда вы получите 20 одинаковых строк.

Comment: Проще выполнить процедурно в цикле.

Comment: Вы не могли бы мне помочь с процедурой. Как будет выглядеть этот цикл?

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko В postgresql никакие вспомогательные таблицы не нужны, потому что есть, представленная в вопросе функция generate_series() которая как раз создает любое нужное количество строк. И я бы не сказал, что в цикле проще.

Comment: @Mike, теперь я уже больше узнал о postgresql. :-)
Собственно, я и не говорил, что эта таблица должна быть постоянной.
В sql server я бы использовал конструктор таблиц непосредственно в запросе. Postgresql позволяет это сделать проще, хотя и нестандартно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Циклов в SQL нет и они не нужны. Потому что язык SQL предназначен для работы с наборами данных, целиком. Нам надо сделать такой запрос, который создаст сразу 20 строк. Для генерации одной строки нам надо 6 символов, для генерации 20 строк нам надо создать 6*20 случайных символов. Причем каждая не четная тройка символов должна быть приведена к нижнему регистру. Это можно сделать пронумеровав все символы, разделить на 3 и привести к нижнему регистру, ориентируясь на остаток от деления на 2. После этого нам надо как то собрать 6 последовательных строк в одну, тут нам поможет группировка по номеру символа деленному на 6 и сборка группы в строку через string_agg. Итого:

```
insert into familiabigt(txt) 
select string_agg( case when num/3 % 2 = 1 then lower(S) else S end, '')
  from (
    SELECT chr((ascii('A') + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) S, -- Случайный символ
           row_number() over()-1 num                              -- Порядковый номер (с 0)
      FROM generate_series(1,6*20)
  ) X
 group by num/6
```